# CURL getting error:14094410:SSL

Tags: php, curl

This is my code. Am trying get information from a server.

But I got stuck in the middle. Please help me.

Am getting error such as

```
[errors] => Array ( [0] => error:14094410:SSL 
                 routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure ) )
```

Below is the code that I have written please check and help me.
Will appreciate any help.

```
public function get_quotes(){
     $reservation_obj->source = "test";
     $reservation_obj->location_code = "test";
     $reservation_obj->start_date = "2010-06-01 19:00";
     $reservation_obj->end_date = "2010-06-04 13:50";


     $reservation_obj->action = "get_quotes";
     $json = json_encode($reservation_obj);
     $curl_opts = array(
     CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: text/json', 'Content-length: '.strlen($json)),
     CURLOPT_POST => true,
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_URL => "https://myserver/test.php",
     CURLOPT_VERBOSE => false,
     CURLOPT_SSLCERT => getcwd()."/newfile.crt.pem",
     CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE => "PEM",
     CURLOPT_SSLKEY=> getcwd()."/newfile.key.pem",
     CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE => "PEM",
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
     CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3
     );

     $curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_opts);
     if(!$response = curl_exec($curl)){
     $response->errors[] = curl_error($curl);
     }
     curl_close($curl);

     if(count($response ->errors)){
      print_r($response);
     }else{

     print_r($response);

     }

     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment out the `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3` line and try again.

They say the SSL v3 is vulnerable (idk much about that, sorry), so many of the servers do not allow it using the v3.

Here is an article if you are interested. https://access.redhat.com/articles/1232123

Please let me know the result after you try it. thanks.